# showing 6 different graphs with 6 different buttons - Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am pretty new to the whole javascript programming (first project).
So I have a PHP page working with a CSS and javascript.
There are 6 Buttons that lift a mask (class) on 6 different graphs.
Button 1  ---> show graph 1
Button 2  ---> show graph 2
.and so on
.
If one graph is already shown and a different one is opened, the first one has to become invisible again.

So I made some research the whole day and figured out a way to achieve that with some functions

```
function choosegraph(){

    var sens1 = document.getElementById ('ButtonSens1');
    sens1.addEventListener ('click', Sensor1Graph, true);
    var sens2 = document.getElementById ('ButtonSens2');
    sens2.addEventListener ('click', Sensor2Graph, true);
    var sens3 = document.getElementById ('ButtonSens3');
    sens3.addEventListener ('click', Sensor3Graph, true);
    var sens4 = document.getElementById ('ButtonSens4');
    sens4.addEventListener ('click', meldung, true);
    var sens5 = document.getElementById ('ButtonSens5');
    sens5.addEventListener ('click', meldung, true);
    var sens6 = document.getElementById ('ButtonSens6');
    sens6.addEventListener ('click', meldung, true);

}

function Sensor1Graph(){
    var element = document.getElementById("lineDia1");
        element.classList.toggle("invisible");
    var element = document.getElementById("lineDia2");
        element.classList.add("invisible");
    var element = document.getElementById("lineDia3");
        element.classList.add("invisible");
    var element = document.getElementById("lineDia4");
        element.classList.add("invisible");
    var element = document.getElementById("lineDia5");
        element.classList.add("invisible");        
    var element = document.getElementById("lineDia6");
        element.classList.add("invisible");        

}

function Sensor2Graph(){
    var element = document.getElementById("lineDia1");
        element.classList.add("invisible");
    var element = document.getElementById("lineDia2");
        element.classList.toggle("invisible");
    var element = document.getElementById("lineDia3");
        element.classList.add("invisible");
    var element = document.getElementById("lineDia4");
        element.classList.add("invisible");
    var element = document.getElementById("lineDia5");
        element.classList.add("invisible");        
    var element = document.getElementById("lineDia6");
        element.classList.add("invisible"); 

function Sensor3Graph(){ ... }    
function Sensor4Graph(){ ... } 
function Sensor5Graph(){ ... } 
function Sensor6Graph(){ ... }
```

So this is working. But I guess there is a way easier and faster way to perform this.
And it would be nice if someone could give me some tips on improving this program.

thank you

EDIT:

some HTML code of 3 graphs that are shown

```
<!-- Line Graphs  -->
    <article class="test invisible" id="lineDia1">  
        <section class="tachos">
            <div id="curve_chart1" style="width: 715px" ></div>
        </section>
    </article>

    <article class="test invisible" id="lineDia2">  
        <section class="tachos">
            <div id="curve_chart2" style="width: 715px" ></div>
        </section>
    </article>

    <article class="test invisible" id="lineDia3">  
        <section class="tachos">
            <div id="curve_chart3" style="width: 715px" ></div>
        </section>
    </article>
```

class -test is the overall visual class   ( yea still not final)
class -invisible is the mask (display: none;)

```
 <body onload="showSensor()">
```

"choosegraph" is called within the "showSensor" function

Comment: You can create all the objects hidden with css style `display: none;` and toggle the display on click

Comment: Tip: working solutions that you're seeking to improve are more fitting on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Hullefu Please include some html code and how you call the `choosegraph` function. Also, what is `meldung`?

Comment: thanks for the fast answers.
"meldung is still a placeholder for the "sensorXGraph" function.  didn't changed that.

The "invisible" class  is   "display: none;" Or are you suggesting to change that completly within css without using javascript? 
Tried that but didn't made it so far for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I see your HTML code is repetitive.We can generate it dynamically.*

> Run the following snippet:

```js
var elements=[];
for(let i=1;i<=6;i++){
 let ele=document.createElement("article");
 ele.classList.add("invisible");
 ele.id=`lineDia${i}`
 let section=document.createElement("section");
 section.class="tachos"
 let div=document.createElement(`curve_chart${i}`);
 div.style.width="750px";
 div.innerHTML=`graph${i}`
 section.innerHTML=div.outerHTML;
 ele.innerHTML=section.outerHTML;
 let btn=document.createElement('button');
 btn.id=`buttonSense${i}`;
 btn.onclick=function(){
   sensorGraph(i)
 }
 btn.innerHTML=`Show graph${i}`;
 document.getElementById("main").appendChild(ele);
 document.getElementById("buttons-div").appendChild(btn);
 elements.push(ele);
}

function sensorGraph(i){
    elements.forEach((element,index)=>{
        if(i-1 == index)
         element.classList.toggle("invisible");
        else
         element.classList.add("invisible");
    });
}
```

```css
.invisible{
 visibility:hidden;
}
#buttons-div{
display:inline-flex;
}
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<div id="main">

</div>
<div id="buttons-div">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I'am going to test and analyse it if I have time for it.

Comment: if you found this answer useful, please upvote it and if you think this is correct answer mark it as correct